# Minimum value of Sum for reals

Tags: maxima-minima

Find minimum value of Sum $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^n a_k^2$ for reals satisfying $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^n a_k=1$ .

This is first time I am encountering such problem . How to approach such problem where there are so many variables and a little information ? Most of time I use AM - GM inequalities and derivatives for maxima and minima but nothing seem to work here .
This was some last year exam question and options are in terms of n .

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwraz inquality.

Comment: Use RMS-Am inequality $\sqrt{\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n}} \ge \frac{\sum x_i}{n}.$